# Upgrading winforms app fails - The process cannot access the file 'C:\...\WinForm.exe' because it is being used by another process

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I implemented a functionality to check if there is a new version of Win Form application.

If there is a new version, I try to copy all the files. Including the executable.

But when my functionality tries to copy the executables, I get error with message

> The process cannot access the file 'C:...\WinForm.exe' because it is
>   being used by another process.

Below the code:

```
public void CopyAll(string sourceFolder, string destFolder)
{
    CopyOutput = new List<string>();

    if (!Directory.Exists(destFolder))
        Directory.CreateDirectory(destFolder);
    string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(sourceFolder);
    foreach (string file in files)
    {
        string name = Path.GetFileName(file);
        string dest = Path.Combine(destFolder, name);
        File.Copy(file, dest, true);
        CopyOutput.Add("File copied: " + dest);
    }
    string[] folders = Directory.GetDirectories(sourceFolder);
    foreach (string folder in folders)
    {
        string name = Path.GetFileName(folder);
        string dest = Path.Combine(destFolder, name);
        CopyAll(folder, dest);
    }
}
```

Comment: use a proper installer, don't write your own.

Comment: You need to close that application before you update its executable. You can inform ask user to close it and do it through separate application.

Comment: @Ben: could you name 1-2 free installers, that have built-in and well-documented auto update support? Links will be useful. (Don't mention ClickOnce, please, it is rather limited).

Comment: replacing the executable used to work when shadowcopy is on (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms404279(v=vs.110).aspx) but there is no point overwriting everything without a forced restart (ending up with updated data files, config files, pictures, ... and the old exe in memory)

Comment: I'm looking for how to implement ClickOnce, couldn't find something usefull yet.

Comment: well... that's a different question. start here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/31kztyey.aspx

Comment: Use ClickOnce and be done with it.  It's a checkbox.  Better than that rubbish bug-fest InstallShield LE or whatever it's called these days

Comment: You could also consider using a "Setup Project" if you need a msi. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/19x10e5c(v=vs.100).aspx But these Template project are only provided until Visual Studio 2010. By the way ClickOnce deployments are working really fine as long as you don't need automated deployment.

Comment: @marco, they'r back: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/bharry/2014/04/18/creating-installers-with-visual-studio/

Comment: I marked this back up because, although the respondees don't link the OPs technical approach, his question is clear and has all the information necessary to answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use ClickOnce or if that doesn't meet your needs, you can build an MSI installer using the Visual Studio extension for that purpose:

- Microsoft Visual Studio 2015 Installer Projects: https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/f1cc3f3e-c300-40a7-8797-c509fb8933b9
- Microsoft Visual Studio 2013 Installer Projects: https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/9abe329c-9bba-44a1-be59-0fbf6151054d

I would not recommend writing your own installer - as you have discovered there is a lot of things you need to get right.

Answer (score 0):

As others have responded, this is probably not the way to approach the problem. But to answer your question directly, the normal solution to this is to copy the new EXE/DLL files to a subfolder, or to different file name (i.e. "MyEXE.exe.new"). Just before you exit your current application instance you launch a simple .net utility application which copies the ".new" files to their intended target, then then utility application launches the newly refreshed .EXE file and quits itself.

With very careful AppDomain handling you might be able to dispense with the utility application, but its far simpler to approach it as two applications.